# Can we create two controllers on eks one is nginx ingress controller and alb ingress controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I have a use case where I need to create two controllers on eks one is nginx ingress controller and alb ingress controller

Comment: I can't think off the top of my mind why you shouldn't be able to do that but what does prompt your question? Did you try and it didn't work?

Comment: Before trying I just wanted to check